# JS: How do I use an initialized class in another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to use an already logged-in twitter client from my index.js file by exporting it and then simply calling it for use in another js file, I'll just call it file2.js

index.js:

```
const twit = require('twit');
const TwitterClient = new twit({

    consumer_key: `${process.env.TWITTER_KEY}`,
    consumer_secret: `${process.env.TWITTER_SECRET}`,
    access_token: `${process.env.TWITTER_TOKEN}`,
    access_token_secret: `${process.env.TWITTER_TOKENSECRET}`,
    timeout_ms: 60 * 1000,
    strictSSL: true
})

module.exports = TwitterClient;
```

file2.js:

```
const { TwitterClient } = require('../../index')

TwitterClient.get('users/lookup', { screen_name: 'Plexversal' }).then(a => {
    console.log(a)
})
```

From what I have already tried to research this should be what I do, the path to the index file is correct as I can see the exported class when I hover over it so I know that's not the issue.

The error that I get from file2 is:

> Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

The exact same function works in the index file and I tried the most basic of methods to get some kind of output with no luck so the syntax is valid. I just want to know what i'm missing.

Thanks.

Comment: You need `const TwitterClient = require('../../index')`

Comment: now I get `TwitterClient.get is not a function`

Comment: What do you get when you run `console.log(TwitterClient)` after requiring it?

Comment: just an empty Object, doing it in index spits out the full object with tokens and such

Comment: Is it possible you're requiring the wrong index file? Because it works for me.

Comment: It can't be, I can hover over the pathname and it shows its correct path. I only have one index.js and I get no cannot find module error

Answer (score 0):

This line assigns TwitterClient to module.exports:

```
module.exports = TwitterClient;
```

This line assumes there's a property on module.exports called TwitterClient:

```
const { TwitterClient } = require('../../index')
```

Pick one or the other:

```
module.exports = TwitterClient
const TwitterClient = require('../../index')
```

or:

```
module.exports.TwitterClient = TwitterClient
// or module.exports = { TwitterClient }
const { TwitterClient } = require('../../index')
```